# Replacing a word in a string of characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple string manipulation program, but I am running into a problem.

**WHAT THE IF SHOULD DO:**

`streetaddress` field is not required to contain the word street, but if it does, it is to be changed to 'Street'.

Current code:

```
<body>
    Name: <input id="NameTextBox" type="text" /> FirstName LastName with a space between<br />
    Street Address: <input id="StreetAddressTextBox" type="text" /> <br />
    City: <input id="CityTextBox" type="text" /> <br />
    State: <input id="StateTextBox" type="text" /> <br />
    Zip: <input id="ZipTextBox" type="text" /> <br />
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Validate Entries" onclick="ValidateandDisplay()" />
    <div id="AddressDiv">If entered correctly, your address will display here.</div>
    
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Split a String" onclick="SplitThis()" />
    <script>

        //need to initialize to empty strings
        var enteredname = "";
        var streetaddress = "";
        var city = "";
        var state = "";
        var zip = "";

        function ValidateandDisplay() {
            enteredname = document.getElementById("NameTextBox").value;
            streetaddress = document.getElementById("StreetAddressTextBox").value;
            city = document.getElementById("CityTextBox").value;
            state = document.getElementById("StateTextBox").value;
            zip = document.getElementById("ZipTextBox").value;

            var isValid = CheckEntries(); // call isValid function here that will
            //                  perform all validation and return with a true or false from CheckEntries
            if (isValid) {
                //string to display
                var correctentries = enteredname + "<br/>" +
                    streetaddress + "<br/>" + city + ", " + state + " " + zip;
                document.getElementById("AddressDiv").innerHTML = correctentries;
            }
            
        }

        function CheckEntries() {
            //perform all checks here
            //use separate ifs to determine each validation requirement
            // alerting the user to the particular problem if something didn't
            // pass validation and returning with a false
            // ALL of your validation MUST be above the return true statement below
            // it will only get to THIS return if all validation (conditions) were ok
            if (enteredname[0] == ' ')
            {
                alert("First position in name field can not be a space.");
                return false;
            }
            if (enteredname.indexOf(" ") == -1)
            {
                alert("no spaces found in entry.");
                return false;
            }
            if (enteredname.toLowerCase().indexOf("miller") == -1)
            {
                alert("miller is not in name field.");
                return false;
            }
            if (state.length != 2)
            {
                alert("State field must be only two characters long.");
                return false;
            }
            if (zip[0] != '4' || zip[1] != '5')
            {
                alert("Zip field must start with 45.");
                return false;
            }
            if (streetaddress.toLowerCase().includes("street")) {
                const streetIncluded = streetaddress.toLowerCase().includes("street");

                // It'll only replace if it exits
                streetaddress = streetaddress.replace("street", "Street");

                return streetIncluded;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: It does not work. In the streetaddress field if I enter Main STREET. I need the program to convert STREET or any version of StReEt to Street. It does not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const streetIncluded = streetaddress.toLowerCase().includes("street");

// It'll only replace if it exits (used regex with i flag so it'll ignore the case)
streetaddress = streetaddress.replace(/street/i, "Street");

return streetIncluded;
```

Your code had problems because:

1. you don't assign the replace value to anything
2. You check in the `if` that the `street` text is **not** included in the `streetaddress`
3. You are replacing only one form of *street* and it's the lowercase one

Comment: Updated code to look like yours and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you get `streetIncluded` as a function argument?

Comment: I don't think so. I have attached my full program above. The code in question is at the very bottom.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Works Great! Thank you!